# An Update in Laravel Framework is returning A new Record

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I am new to PHP and Laravel. I have learned much, but I am having a problem seeing my error in what should be a simple task.

I have a form which is populated from data in a MySQL database. When I submit it, it creates a new record instead of updating the existing record. This is the form action that I am using:

```
 <form action="{{route('updateAlert', $alert->id)}}" method="post" name="saveAlert" id="saveAlert" class="needs-validation"
 @csrf
 @method("PUT")
   ///form fields here
</form>
```

Here are the two related routes.  editAlert brings you to the form above.  updateAlert is supposed to bring you to the update method on my AlertController.

```
Route::get('/alerts/edit/{id}', 'AlertController@edit')->name('editAlert');
Route::put('/alerts/edit/{id}', 'AlertController@update')->name('updateAlert');
```

Here is what my AlertController looks like:

```
/**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

    public function update(Request $request, Alert $alert)
    {
        $alert->type = $request->type;
        $alert->title = $request->title;
        $alert->body = $request->body;
        $alert->link = $request->link;
        $alert->eff_dt = Carbon::parse($request->eff_dt);
        $alert->exp_dt = Carbon::parse($request->exp_dt);
        $alert->note = $request->note;
        $alert->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $alert->save();

        return redirect()->route('viewAlerts')->with('success', 'Your alert has been updated.');

    }
```

What am I missing? I have the same basic code in another section of the app that is working as expected. Thanks in advance.

Comment: because your type hinted parameter of your controller method does not match the name of the route parameter you have defined ... if you want implicit binding to happen they have to match otherwise you get dependency injection which would be a new non-existing model instance .. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#implicit-binding

Comment: Your routes should look like `Route::put('/alerts/edit/{alert}'`, then when your method type hints `update(Request $request, Alert $alert)` the model will be found.

Answer (score 1):

You Are Not Fetching your row id. You need to use model and pass your id to your model to update any specific row.

Ex.
I the model name just pass your model name.

```
    public function update(Request $request, Alert $alert)
    {
            $alert          = ModelName::find($alert);
            $alert->type    = $request->type;
            $alert->title   = $request->title;
            $alert->body    = $request->body;
            $alert->link    = $request->link;
            $alert->eff_dt  = Carbon::parse($request->eff_dt);
            $alert->exp_dt  = Carbon::parse($request->exp_dt);
            $alert->note    = $request->note;
            $alert->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
            $alert->save();
            return redirect()->route('viewAlerts')->with('success', 'Your alert has been updated.');

    }
```

Comment: This is a short-sighted fix. The Laravel way is to use route model binding, which OP is 90% of the way to doing correctly.  Ignoring that and manually looking up the model is not a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

To update things in Laravel, you need a query builder object; Alert $alert returns an object of the model, so it can not be used to update things.

> Note: find method is a special method whose objects can be used to update records, unlike the "first" method.

So your code must be changed to:

```
public function update(Request $request, Alert $alert)
{
   $alert = Alert::where('id', $alert->id); // or: Alert::find($alert->id);
   $alert->type = $request->type;
   $alert->title = $request->title;
   $alert->body = $request->body;
   $alert->link = $request->link;
   $alert->eff_dt = Carbon::parse($request->eff_dt);
   $alert->exp_dt = Carbon::parse($request->exp_dt);
   $alert->note = $request->note;
   $alert->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
   $alert->save();
}
```

Comment: This is a short-sighted fix. The Laravel way is to use route model binding, which OP is 90% of the way to doing correctly.  Ignoring that and manually looking up the model is not a good solution.